# smarty compliler giving error decode_properties()

Tags: php, server, smarty

On compiling file only have `html tags` smarty compiler giving errors in server error log

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function _decodeProperties() on null in /home/ubuntu/apps/site/default/public/templates_c/bootstrap3_2016^7b9eb976f5ea245928708b0598ce0cd72643b725_0.file.bitlocker_how_encrypt.tpl.php:6

**code of file**

```
<div style="width:620px;height:419px;">
<div id="simmain2102133074" style="position:relative;width:620px;height:495px;font-family:windows8Font;">
    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/jigyaasa_content_static/bitlocker_how_encrypt_000EAM.png">
    <div id="simID0" class=" only-dragable" style="position:absolute; top:174px; left:34px; height:20px; width:20px;">
        <input type="radio" class="simID0 simradio" id="encrypt_use_disk" rel="encrypt_use_disk" name="select_encrypt_mechanism" group="dialogradio" checked="checked">
    </div>
    <div id="simID1" class=" only-dragable" style="position:absolute; top:198px; left:34px; height:20px; width:20px;">
        <input type="radio" class="simID1 simradio" id="encrypt_entire_drive" rel="encrypt_entire_drive" name="select_encrypt_mechanism" group="dialogradio">
    </div>
    <div id="simID2" class=" drag-resize" style="position:absolute; top:388px; left:468px; height:20px; width:66px;">
        <button type="button" class="simID2 sim_button commonClassName" id="bitlocker_encryptddrive" rel="bitlocker_encryptddrive" group="dialogbutton">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div id="simID3" class=" drag-resize" style="position:absolute; top:388px; left:543px; height:20px; width:66px;">
        <button type="button" class="simID3 sim_button close_dialog" id="bitlocker_encrypt_cancel" rel="bitlocker_encrypt_cancel" group="dialogbutton">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**IS there any HTML validator rule for Smarty compiler**

Comment: Show us additionally what you tried to compile, not only what the output is.

Comment: i tried to compile that tpl file whose code is given

Comment: There is nothing related to Smarty in the posted code. How looks the PHP code that uses Smarty?